# Where can I download a snapshot of the Lightning network topology?

Tags: lightning-network

I want to study the properties of the Lightning network graph. Is there a way to obtain a reasonably fresh snapshot containing nodes and channels (say, in JSON format)? There are multiple explorers available (e.g. listed in [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/85460/31712)), but AFAIK none of them provides the underlying data for download.

(I could just launch my own node and query the data with `allnodes` / `allchannels` or a similar command, but that requires synching a non-pruned full node, which I'm trying to avoid at the moment.)

UPD: 1ML does provide *some* JSON (look for the JSON button on various pages). For example, https://1ml.com/testnet/node?json=true gives the JSON description of the top 50 nodes. I haven't found the way to get this data for all nodes though.

UPD2: a related question: [Obtaining Lightning network graph data](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76189/obtaining-lightning-network-graph-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE (march 2022):**

The lnresearch repository has historic snapshots at https://github.com/lnresearch/topology (as pointed out in [the other answer by damianodamiano](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/105358/81940) )

if you want a recent snapshot you can use c-lightning and run:

```
lightning-cli listchannels > your_channel_file.json
```

of course the later requires you to first connect to some other nodes and sync gossip.

**Old reply:**

As far as I know currently noone explicitly provides this dataset / snapshot. However romperts recksplorer works with providing this dataset from lnd to the browser and have javascript visualize it. so you could do: `wget https://rompert.com/networkgraphv2` but that is a little bit dirty.

The "easiest" way to achieve what you are looking for by doing it properly is probably to extract `gossipd` from `lightningd`. As you know c Lightning has this darmonized architecture so there gossipd should be able to run standalone, peer with nodes and download sync the network graph.

I might be interested in helping to run gossipd as a standalone tool. We could also just implement the gossip protocol ourselves as that part of lightning is pretty standalone.

Hope these two suggestions help

Comment: "gossipd should be able to run standalone" - does this imply that as of now I'd have to tweak the code and re-build c-lightning to be able to launch `gossipd` separately?

Comment: Yeah. That is exactly what I was trying to say (: in that way you won't need Bitcoind or anything like that but you will just connect to the gossip protocol / peer network

Comment: btw you could do `wget https://rompert.com/networkgraphv2 | jq '.' | less` to download the latest gossip store from rompert's lnd node (I will also edit this to the answer)

Comment: Wow, that (using rompert.com) is _really_ helpful, thanks a lot! Hope the node maintainers don't mind occasional downloads of their data for research purposes...

Comment: Any update to this question? the rompert.com website seems unreachable. Is there any alternative?

Comment: just edited my answer and provided a more stable link to : https://github.com/lnresearch/topology (as pointed out by damianodamiano sorry oversaw it!)

Answer (score 0):

https://ln.alhur.es/ provides a download link for their historical channel database from this link: https://ln.alhur.es/static/channels.db

Answer (score 0):

There is also this repository on Github: https://github.com/lnresearch/topology